# Greybox + Flowplayer problems

Tags: javascript, html, video, dhtml

Hey all I am having a huge problem here evenafter following every step of the tutorial given here to put in a video on a popup greybox ..
[The tutorial](http://blog.beacontechnologies.com/making-a-slick-popup-video-player-using-greybox-flowplayer/)

now, the only change i have made is i have a folder inside the folder graybox called graybox which holds the JS and css files.

so my script code reads like this ..

```
    <script>var GB_ROOT_DIR = "/greybox/";</script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="greybox/greybox/AJS.js"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript" src="greybox/greybox/AJS_fx.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="greybox/greybox/gb_scripts.js"></script>
<link href="greybox/greybox/gb_styles.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
```

there is a folder called video which has a video called video.flv.

now I have linked a text to open as shown in the tutorial .. the code is

```
<a title="Noodle Demo" href="player.html?filename=videos/noodle.flv">Demo</a>
```

when i click on the link on the web page the window opens up right but the window reads page not found .. I have the required player.html too and that is a copy paste from the tutorial, i;ve changed all the required version numbers of flowplayer etc. Please help me.

Comment: Usually the addons like this use the rel tag in the `<a>` as parameters. :) Are you sure you don't need a rel tag?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the rel tag. :)

`<a rel="gb_page_center[560, 450]" href="player.html?filename=videos/noodle.flv">`

God bless tutorials. For better centering you can get the middle of the site by jQuery for example.

```
<a rel="gb_page_center[560, 450]" id="player" href="player.html?filename=videos/noodle.flv">
<script type="text=javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    cenx = $(window).width();
    ceny = $(window).height();
    $("#player").attr("rel", "gb_page_center["+cenx/2+", "+ceny/2+"]");
});
</script>
```

But it requires jquery from [jquery website](http://jquery.com).

Comment: hey guys problem solved i had the Greybox folders in a diff folder form root and that caused the malfunctioning :)